# Do I Need to Purchase Credits to Develop a 3D Viewer Using AutoDesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge

Do I need to purchase credits to develop and deploy an AutoDesk Forge 3D viewer on our web based collaboration platform? If yes, can you please provide details for what the credits are for?

Answer (score 0):

Yes if you are only after Viewer then basically you'd need cloud credits for (only) the below service and charged for each translation depending on their source/target formats (regardless of how long the job lasts):

- [Model Derivative](https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/reference/http/) - Translate models from their original formats to SVF so Viewer can load them

You can find pricing info [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-pricing-explained-1-how-access-forge) and [this blog](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/forge-pricing-explained-1-how-access-forge) explains our pricing well in greater details as well.

Once you sign up for Forge you'd be given 100 free credits for trial and you'd need to purchase credits after you [run out of them](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/handling-developer-status-not-active-response).

Buckets (Data Management) and uploading/downloading objects/derivatives are free of charge BTW ...